# Need Recommendation on css for implementing Toggle Switch Button

Tags: javascript, html, css

My requirement was to show a toggle button with a message on it's right for mobile website. I have implemented this but I am not sure how good it is & if it will work on most of the mobile browsers. I am very new to the UI development & this is the first time I have implemented a UI component. To give an idea, this final implemented result look somewhat similar to [this](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*PjHEsBxh7B9BrYARqHcujQ.jpeg)

I have broken down this requirement into 5 parts -
1. The container - Parent div 
2. Checkbox. - Hidden checkbox behind button 
3. The button 
4. The inner circle of button  
5. The message string which will be shown on the right.

Additionally, this button needs to be disabled for first few seconds of page. By disabling, I mean it should be unclickable & it's UX would be little different so that user knows that it's disabled.

HTML -

```
    <div class = "toggleSwitchContainer">
        <div class = "my-toggle-button" disabled = "true">
            <input type="checkbox" id = "checkBox">
            <div class = "toggle-switch-inner-circle" disabled = "true"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "messageString" disabled = "true">
            <text>Some message</text>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
.toggleSwitchContainer {
    padding : 10px;
}
.my-toggle-button[disabled] {
    width : 40px;
    height : 20px;
    background-color : #dddddd47;
    border-radius : 30px;
    border-color : #80808017;

}

.my-toggle-button {
    width : 44px;
    height : 22px;
    background-color : #eff0f3;
    border-radius : 30px;
    position : relative;
    transition : all 300ms ease-in-out;
    display : inline-block;
    border : solid 1px;
    border-color : #80808080;
}

.my-toggle-button.active {
    background-color : #ff7800;
}


.my-toggle-button > .toggle-switch-inner-circle {
    position : absolute;
    width : 20px;
    height : 20px;
    background-color : #eff0f3;
    border-radius : 50%;
    border : solid 1px;
    border-color : #80808080;
    transition : all 300ms ease-in-out;

    top : 0;
}

.my-toggle-button.active > .toggle-switch-inner-circle {
    margin-left : 22px;

    background-color : #fff;
}

.messageString[disabled] {
    color : #00000024;
}
.messageString {
    display : inline-block;
    padding : 10px;
}

.my-toggle-button input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

JS
Function to handle click -

```
toggleSwitchObject.unbind().click(function() {
    toggleSwitchObject[0].classList.toggle('active');//On click inner circle will be moved to right & background color will change.
    callRequiredFunctionNow();
});
```

Disable -

```
 containerDomNode.children().attr('disabled', true);
```

So, the idea is to append a css property called 'active' on click of the switch so that the inner circle is moved to right & background color is changed. I need to know if there is any risky css property I am using which may not work on many browsers. Specifically, the transition property looks scary to me. Is there any scope of improvement in this implementation?

Comment: You can use libraries like jQuery UI or Twitter Bootstrap, they have toggle buttons like this.

Comment: Using additional libraries is not an option for me.